# React clone element to modify a child component and keep ref in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, react-ref

I used to have refs in my component when rendering, and it worked:

```
// props.children is ReactElement<HTMLDivElement>[]
const [childRefs] = useState<RefObject<any>[]>(props.children.map(() => createRef()));

// working code, all the variables (props, childRefs etc) are defined earlier in scope
return <div {...props}>
    {
        props.children.map((c, i) => <div key={i} ref={childRefs[i]}>{c}</div >)
    }
</div>
```

Basically I'm using the refs to imperatively directly set some transforms to style as mouse moves on JS `mousemove` event.

However, I now need to inject some CSS class into the passed component automatically. I've created a component (named `Layer`) that takes the child element, clones it, sets the CSS class, and returns it:

```
function Layer(props:LayerProps){
    const elem = cloneElement(props.children, {...props.children.props,
        className: styles['layer']
    });
    return elem;
}
```

I've updated the main component like this too:

```
return <div {...props}>
    {
        props.children.map((c, i) => <Layer key={i} ref={childRefs[i]}>{c}</Layer>)
    }
</div>
```

However now my `ref`s aren't passed now, understandibly, as the `Layer` functional component can't have a `ref` (as it's a function). When I try to set the `ref` to `Layer` it can't, and have this error (understandably):

```
(property) ref: React.RefObject<any>
Type '{ children: ReactElement<HTMLDivElement, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>; key: number; ref: RefObject<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LayerProps'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LayerProps'.ts(2322)
```

If I try to forward the `ref` using `forwardRef` it doesn't have anything to set that ref to as I'm just modifying the passed child element and returning it, not returning a new element like `<div>...</div>` that I could forward ref to like `<div ref={forwardedRef}>...</div>`.

How can I modify the CSS class *and* keep a `ref` to the object? I know how to do each one (if I just need to add class I `cloneElement`, if I just need to ref it I use `forwardRef` and pass it to the child component in JSX) yet I couldn't figure out being able to do both at the same time.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can define `ref` property on `LayerProps` and later pass it to child component.

Comment: @user1672994 but how do I "pass it" to child component since I'm not creating the child component and just cloning an existing one?

Comment: You are cloning the child element using `cloneElement` so while cloning it you are pass the ref as part of config parameter (personally I've not done it yet, but based on [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) it seems it is possible.. like `cloneElement(props.children {...props.children.props, className: styles['layer'], ref={props.ref} });`

Comment: @user1672994 yup indeed it's possible. i was confused because TypeScript linter tells me that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after a bit digging and experimenting I've realized I can give `ref` "prop" (which isn't technically a real prop, but anyway) in `cloneElement` just like any prop.

I've ended up forwarding ref to the functional component, and provided `ref` as a prop to the newly cloned element, and it worked.

Yet, the TypeScript definitions are incorrectly flagging `ref` property as non-existent while it works perfectly. I needed it to cast the props to `any` to silence the linter error though:

```
const Layer = forwardRef((props:LayerProps, ref:any) => {
    const elem = cloneElement(props.children, {
        className: `${props.children.props.className ?? ''} ${styles['layer']}`,
        ref: ref
    } as any); // as any fixes ref complaining
    return elem;
});
```

And in many component:

```
 return <div {...props}>
        {
            props.children.map((c, i) => <Layer key={i} ref={childRefs[i]}>{c}</Layer>)
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: No need to do `...props.children.props` since all existing props are always passing to the cloned component. You only put as second parameter (`props`) what you want to *add/override*